# Cambiar los valores a un objeto / clase

Tags: python

Lo que quiero hacer es tener un personaje con valores de vida, fuerza y agilidad que pueden ser modificados al subir de nivel. Pero no sé como sobrescribir los valores de estos parámetros.

```py
class Pelea:
    #Asigna los valores de los personajes para poder ser usada dentro de las funciones
    def __init__(self, nombre, ataques, XP, modif_daño, vida):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.ataques = ataques
        self.vida = vida
        self.modif_daño = modif_daño
        self.XP = XP

    if self.XP >= Sig_nivel:
            Stats()

def Stats():
    global vida, fuerza, agilidad, Sig_nivel
    print("VIDA: %i\nFUERZA: %.2f\nAGILIDAD: %.2f" % (vida, fuerza, agilidad))
    print("\nTienes un punto de experiencia, donde lo quieres usar: Vida = V, Fuerza = F, Agilidad = A")
    continuar = True
    
    while continuar == True:
        res = input("V / F / A: ").upper()
        if res == "V":
            vida += 20
            continuar = False
        elif res == "F":
            # fuerza += 10
            modif_daño += 10
            continuar = False
        elif res == "A":
            # agilidad += 15
            modif_daño += 15
            continuar = False
        else:
            print("Error: Respuesta invalida")
    Sig_nivel *= 1.5
    print("Siguiente nivel: %i" % Sig_nivel)

# Esta función de Stats() es la que no me funciona, sé que está mal, pero espero se entienda lo que supuestamente debe de hacer

def Estadisticas_todos(nombre_jugador, ataques_arma, modif_daño, XP = XP):
    global Player
    Player = Pelea(nombre_jugador, ataques_arma, XP, modif_daño, vida = vida)
```

Comment: No te sirve de nada declarar como globales esas variables, pues son atributos de una instancia de clase. Son propios de cada instancia que crees. La forma correcta sería `instancia. atributo = valor`. Por ejemplo `Player.vida += 20`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una función (método) dentro de tu clase que sea tipo `def LevelUp():` la cual llames cada vez que el personaje suba de nivel, y suba las estadísticas, digamos un 5% cada vez que sube. Haciendo uso de tus `self.vida`, así ya podrías modificar esos valores sin tener que hacer uso de las variables globales.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).